# Modifying the code I got from WikiHow's Secure Session Login script

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

I wanted to implement the secure login script from [WikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL) in my project. I have got it working in CodeIgniter. I want to modify it a bit by logging out a user when he closes the browser (unless he checked `Remember Me` on the login page).

This is the login function (assume every variable is set because the function won't be called unless they are).

```
public function login() {
    $error_msg = array();

    // the email and password validation is here
    // if error is found its pushed into the $error_msg array

    // find the user corresponding to the given email address
    $sql = "SELECT user_id, username, password, salt FROM users WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $email);
    if ($query) {
        if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            $result = $query->row();

            // user is found
            // hash the pass with the salt
            $password = hash('sha512', $password.$result->salt);

            // check for number of tries
            if ($this->check_brute($result->user_id) == TRUE) {
                // account locked for repeated failed login attempts
                $error_msg[] = "<p>Account is locked due to repeated failed login attempts.</p>";
                // return FALSE;
            } else {
                // check password
                if ($password == $result->password) {
                    $user_browser = $this->security->xss_clean($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); // browser
                    $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $result->user_id);
                    $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", "", $result->username);

                    // i want to set the cookie expiry time depending on the
                    // remember me checkbox
                    if ($_POST['remember']) {
                    }

                    // i am guessing somekinda cookie manipulation should
                    // take place here

                    // assign session variables
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', $password.$user_browser);

                    return TRUE; // login success
                } else {
                    // wrong password input
                    // add activity in database
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO login_attempts (user_id, time) VALUES (?, ?)";
                    $this->db->query($sql, array($result->user_id, time()));
                    $error_msg[] = "<p>ERR PASS: Username/password combination is incorrect.</p>";
                    // return FALSE;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // user doesnt exist
            // return FALSE;
            $error_msg[] = "<p>NO USR: Username/password combination is incorrect.</p>";
        }
    }

    return $error_msg;
}
```

And this is the code for the session starting:

```
public function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = "sec_session_id";
    $secure = FALSE; // dev mode
    $httponly = TRUE;

    if(ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
        $error_msg = '<p>Could not initiate a secure session.</p>';
        return $error_msg;
    }

    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params(
        $cookieParams['lifetime'],
        $cookieParams['path'],
        $cookieParams['domain'],
        $secure,
        $httponly);

    session_name($session_name);
    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id(TRUE);
    return TRUE;
}
```

The only place where there is a reference to cookies is in the logout function where it is unset. What should I do to set the cookie expiry time when a user logs in depending on their choice on "Remember me"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem using this script and this is the solution that I came up with.

In your login function, add this code:

(I am assuming `$_POST['remember']` will be = 1 if user wants to be remembered, 0 otherwise)

```
if ($_POST['remember']) {
     $_SESSION['remember'] = $_POST['remember'];
}
```

Then in the function `sec_session_start()` add this after `session_start()`:

```
...

session_name($session_name);
session_start();            

if($_SESSION['remember'] == 1){ session_set_cookie_params(60*60*24*60); }

session_regenerate_id(true);  

...
```

The lifetime can obviously be changed to suit you. I chose 2 months for this example.

What this code is effectively doing is setting another session which contains the information as to whether or not the user wants to remembered.

The cookie is then initially set with the default value that your server has set for session lifetimes, but if the remember session has a value of 1, it changes this to the lifetime you have set.

I've not extensively tested this so let me know if any issues arise.

Comment: Thank you. This indeed helped me fix the issue I was having. The only modification it required was to add an `isset` conditional to my `$_POST['remember']`:
    `if (isset($_POST['remember']) && $_POST['remember'] == 1)`

Although this method works just fine for my case, how would I proceed if I want to log out a user who didn't want to be remembered when he closes the browser?

Comment: Change your code in `sec_session_start()` to: `if($_SESSION['remember'] == 1){ session_set_cookie_params(60*60*24*60); } else{ session_set_cookie_params(0); }`

Comment: I have tried adding the `session_set_cookie_params(0)` but when I reopen the browser the user is still logged in. Anything I should be looking at (like in the browser or server config files)?